# Active Record Association Type Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested results upon matches like this

/matches/16/results/13/edit

Where I have the following select field, this shows the correct information ( team.name and its team.id)

```
<%= f.collection_select :winner, @select_winner_loser, :id, :name %>
```

Now when I try to edit my result and selecting a winner I get this:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch *Team(#10504340) expected, got String(#6163240)*

*"Raised when an object assigned to an association has an incorrect type."* http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationTypeMismatch.html

Winner is a **team** object, **result.rb** looks like this

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :match
    belongs_to  :winner, class_name: "Team"
    belongs_to  :loser, class_name: "Team"
end
```

@select_winner_loser comes from my results_controller

```
  def edit
    @select_winner_loser = []
    @select_winner_loser << @match.top
    @select_winner_loser << @match.bottom
  end
```

Match.top & bottom is also team objects

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :top, class_name: "Team"
    belongs_to  :bottom, class_name: "Team"
    ...
    belongs_to  :result
end
```

I dont see why I would get this since I have the correct objects in my select field, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change

```
<%= f.collection_select :winner, @select_winner_loser, :id, :name %>
```

to

```
<%= f.collection_select :winner_id, @select_winner_loser, :id, :name %>
```

and your permitted parameters accordingly. Rails will create a `Team` object when it sees the `_id` in the name.

Comment: Thank you lunr :), had to change my migration file, I had winner instead of winner_id in my db and made the change you pointed out.